# autocomplete "self" in pycharm/atom

Tags: pycharm, atom-editor

When editing python in Sublime text, typing *dot* followed by *tab* key converts it to `self.`. Is there a way to achieve a similar functionality in pycharm and/or atom text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Atom by creating a custom [snippet](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/). Open your snippets (you can run the "Application: Open Your Snippets" command from the [command palette](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics/#command-palette) to do so) and add the following:

```coffeescript
'.source.python':
  'self.':
    prefix: '.'
    description: 'self.'
    body: 'self.'
```